# Inserting a random value into a textarea using selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, ui-automation

I have the following selenium markup:

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>css=input.some-text</td>
    <td> "Some text here, which has to be randomized" </td>
</tr>
```

I want the text to be a random number rather than a fixed string. Is it possible to achieve this using the Selenium IDE alone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<td>type</td>
<td>css=input.some-text</td>
<td>javascript{"uvu" + Math.floor(Math.random()*15000) + "@gmail.com";}</td>
```

In above I just show you example for random email. You want other value if so you can customize it.